# Arrow symbol with circular headed in latex

Tags: latex

I need to use a right arrow symbol in latex such that its left endpoint be a circle (or bullet). I have already tried the following:

```
\def\cra{\hbox{$\multimapdotinv$}\kern-1.5pt\hbox{$\rightarrow$}}%\rightarrow$}}
```

but when I have used it in a formula like

```
$G =G=(\X,\rightarrow,\leftrightarrow,\car,\multimapdotboth)$
```

the result was

[image]

As you can see it does not fit. I have also tried TikZ but it did not work too. Is there anyway that I can make it better?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that includes all packages necessary to compile your code. If I guess a few packages and remove some typos, I get a nice looking arrow https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9BE1.png

Comment: Thank you. In fact you answered my question. I just needed to change -1.5pt to -6.5pt to find the good looking result.

Comment: Good to hear that your were able to solve your problem yourself! Can you sum things up in a short answer? This will ensure that future users with the same problem will find your solution.